# Is there a way to do math with hexadecimals in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, p2p

I'm working with P2P and would like to allow peers a way to find each other. I'm structuring my network where each peer has an ideal set of peers to look for in the network. The IDs of these peers are in hexadecimal format. While in the network, a node constantly searches for peers who have IDs which are closest to it's ideal location (based on its own peer-id).

The easiest way to see who is closest and find other peers in the network is to treat the IDs as if they are numbers. Converting to ints before performing mathematical operations would severely complicate things.

Comment: Hexadecimal is not a class in Python.  It can be represented only by a string, and you cannot do mathematical operations with strings.  You need to convert to something else to do that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you reference something in hex with Python, it's represented as an integer value. See: `>>> 0x0F` yields `15`.

Comment: @hichris123 All of my IDs are 15 byte hexadecimal strings. Working in a 16 based system gets complicated when you're trying to figure out where in the number system, your ID actually rests and where the continuum actually starts over. With 10 based systems, this can be found out with simple subtraction and addition.

Comment: Yes, you can do math with hexadecimals in python.  For example, you can can write `i = 0xaf00 + 0xb3c9` or `print 0xFF * 0xA09F`

Comment: Hexadecimal is a particular representation of an integer. Of course you can do maths with integers.

Comment: How severe is *'severe'*?

Comment: @SciProg, I had done that but didn't include the 0x at the beginning. Thank you.

Comment: you should separate the concept of representation from the concept of the number itself ... it should not be overly complicated to do math with it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> a = 0xA
>>> b = 0xa
>>> a + b
20
>>> hex(a + b)
'0x14'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal and decimal, or any other type of encoding, really, is fundamentally just 1's and 0's. `0xa0` is identical to `160` which is identical to `0b10100000` and so on. When you do "math with hexadecimal," the "with hexadecimal" is entirely peripheral. If you have a hexidecimal string such as `"0xa0"` and want to convert that into a number that you can use, then just do something like:

```
def from_hex(hexdigits):
    return int(hexdigits, 16)

x = "0xa0"
y = "0x10"
z = hex(from_hex(x) + from_hex(y))
print(z) # => 0xb0
```

There's no real way around it unless you want to create your own custom subclass from `int` which just isn't worth it.

Comment: you don't need to take away the `'0x'` for `int` to work: `int("0x2a",16)` yield 42